# Plot Percent Error

Tags: r, plot, graph

I am trying to plot 3 graphs with the same axes in the same figure.
The first of which, the "y-values" are in percentages.
The other 2 are in decimal points, and I am trying to convert to percentage.

I initially worked with the following code:

```
plot(timeSP500[(N+1):nSP500],sigmaSP500[(N+1):nSP500],type='l', ylim=c(0, 0.05))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(timeSP500[(N+1):nSP500],sqrt(EWSP500[(N+1):(nSP500)]),type='l')
par(new=TRUE)
plot(timeSP500[(N+1):nSP500],sqrt(UVdevSP500[(N+1):(nSP500)]),type='l')
```

There was no issue with the output, BUT it was not what I wanted because for the second and third graphs, they are in decimal places and not percentages. So I added in the percent function.

```
plot(timeSP500[(N+1):nSP500],sigmaSP500[(N+1):nSP500],type='l', ylim=c(0, 0.05))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(timeSP500[(N+1):nSP500],percent(sqrt(EWSP500[(N+1):(nSP500)])),type='l')
par(new=TRUE)
plot(timeSP500[(N+1):nSP500],percent(sqrt(UVdevSP500[(N+1):(nSP500)])),type='l')
```

With this I get the error

> Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
>       2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>       3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Which is very weird, because if say I output `percent(sqrt(EWSP500[(N+1):(nSP500)]))` only, there seems to be no error in the output, but I cannot output it in the graph as above.

Comment: Please try to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), perhaps by using `dput` or some simulated data.

Comment: And when you are using functions from a package, it is helpful to indicate which packages were used, e.g. `library(memisc)`